# How to display data on textbox based on selected value from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I need data from database on my textbox when i choose the particular data in drop-down list.
I do the following code but it give me the number instead of description.

```
int s1 = DropDownList3.SelectedIndex;

SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("Select description from vul_auto where finding_id= " + s1,con);

TextBox3.Text =(query.ExecuteNonQuery()).ToString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected. You would use this to do an insert/update/delete, not to select data. Instead, you should use `ExecuteScalar`.

Also, as a general best practice, always use parameterised queries instead of concatenating, specially when you are accepting input from user.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourconnectionstring))
{
    string sql = "Select description from vul_auto where finding_id=@id";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = s1;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle exception
    }
}
```

As @user3713775 mentions in his answer, use `Convert.ToString` to handle null values.

Answer (score 1):

@shree.pat18 is correct.
Use query.ExecuteScalar() & use ConvertToString() instead of ToString() for more robustness.
like TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(query.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: That's a good catch to use `Convert.ToString()`. I have included it in my answer.